# error con matriz en python (metodo de gauss-jordan)(numpy)

Tags: python, numpy

Buen día estimados, implemente el metodo de gauss-jordan en python de la siguiente manera y esta funcionando:

```
#La idea de este metodo es que el usuario ingrese una matriz MxM y un vector de tamano M
import numpy
def gaussJordan(m):
    #creamos una matriz, un vector lleno de ceros, y el vector solucion con la misma cantidad de zeros
    matrix = numpy.zeros((m,m))
    vector = numpy.zeros((m))
    x = numpy.zeros((m))
    #se llena la matriz y el vector
    for r in range(0, m):
        for c in range(0, m):
            matrix[(r), (c)] =(input("Elemento a[" + str(r+1)+"," +str(c+1)+"] "))
        vector[(r)]=(input('b[]'+str(r+1)+']: '))
    #asi funciona el metodo
    for k in range(0, m):
        for r in range(k+1, m):
            factor=(matrix[r,k]/matrix[k,k])
            vector[r]=vector[r]-(factor*vector[k])
            for c in range(0,m):
                matrix[r,c]=matrix[r,c]-(factor*matrix[k,c])

    x[m-1]=vector[m-1]/matrix[m-1, m-1]

    for r in range(m-2, -1, -1):
        suma = 0
        for c in range(0,m):
            suma=suma+matrix[r,c]*x[c]
        x[r]=(vector[r]-suma)/matrix[r, r]  
    return x

m = int(input('Valor de m:'))
print(gaussJordan(m))
```

El problema esta en que un compañero me pidió que si seria posible que en vez de ingresar m en el método y que luego este construya la matriz, pudiese ingresar la matriz y el vector ya hechos, y me pareció un cambio sencillo pero me tope con un par de errores que no comprendo la verdad, primero al ingresar la matriz [[2,6,1],[1,2,-1],[5,7,-4]] me retornaba un error en el que al parecer no lo reconocia como una matriz asi que use numpy.matrix y lo mismo con el vector por si las dudas numpy.array. Después de esto no tuvo problemas en ejecutarse el método pero por alguna razón me retorna un resultado diferente al que debería ser... cuando lo ejecuto llenando la matriz dentro del método, si retorna el resultado que debe ser, debería retornar [10, -3, 5] pero me retorna [21.5, -8, 12] si alguien sabe decirme el porque se lo agradezco mucho, no creo que sea problema del algoritmo, porque arrojaría un resultado incorrecto en el que si pide llenar la matriz internamente, creo que es problema de como esta leyendo la matriz el programa, LOS DATOS QUE USO PARA LA PRUEBA SON MATRIZ = [[2,6,1],[1,2,-1],[5,7,-4]] VECTOR = [7,-1,9] aquí esta el código:

```
#La idea de este metodo es que el usuario ingrese una matriz MxM y un vector de tamano M
import numpy
def gaussJordan(matriz, vector):

    matrix = numpy.matrix(matriz)
    vector = numpy.array(vector)
    m = len(vector)
    x = numpy.zeros((m))
    #se llena la matriz y el vector
##    for r in range(0, m):
##        for c in range(0, m):
##            matrix[(r), (c)] =(input("Elemento a[" + str(r+1)+"," +str(c+1)+"] "))
##        vector[(r)]=(input('b[]'+str(r+1)+']: '))

    #asi funciona el metodo
    for k in range(0, m):
        for r in range(k+1, m):
            factor=(matrix[r,k]/matrix[k,k])
            vector[r]=vector[r]-(factor*vector[k])
            for c in range(0,m):
                matrix[r,c]=matrix[r,c]-(factor*matrix[k,c])

    x[m-1]=vector[m-1]/matrix[m-1, m-1]
    #print (x[m-1])

    for r in range(m-2, -1, -1):
        suma = 0
        for c in range(0,m):
            suma=suma+matrix[r,c]*x[c]
        x[r]=(vector[r]-suma)/matrix[r, r]  
    return x

print(gaussJordan([[2,6,1],[1,2,-1],[5,7,-4]],[7,-1,9]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que NumPy tiene tipado estático y homogéneo. Me explico, si se declara un array de enteros este solo puede almacenar enteros y si es de float32 solo puede almacenar floats de 32 bits. Esto es importante porque una lista de Python puede almacenar cualquier variedad de objetos aunque sean de diferente tipo dentro de la misma lista y cambiar el tipo de un elemento dado en cualquier momento (realmente solo guarda objetos sin importarle lo que sean).

Cuando usas `input` tus arrays `vector` y `matrix` son creados mediante `numpy.zeros` que retorna un **array de float de 64 bits**. Durante tu algoritmo tanto `vector` como `matrix` pueden llegar a tener que almacenar floats, en este caso no hay problema y el método funciona.

Cuando usas la lista para construir ambos arrays **se crea un array de un tipo determinado según el tipo de datos contenidos en las listas de entrada**, es decir, se crean **dos arrays de enteros** en este caso. El problema es que estos arrays **no pueden almacenar decimales** por lo que si haces algo como:

```
vector[0] = 4/3
```

`vector[0]` no almacena 1.33333 como podemos esperar, sino **solo la parte entera** (1). Se limita a almacenar la parte entera pero no lanza ninguna excepción por la diferencia de tipos. Esto causa importantes errores acumulativos en el algoritmo y terminas con errores importantes en el resultado.

La solución es simple, fuerza el tipo de los arrays para que sean de tipo floats aunque las listas de entrada sean enteros usando el argumento `dtype`:

```
import numpy
def gaussJordan(matriz, vector):

    matrix = numpy.array(matriz, dtype=numpy.float64)
    vector = numpy.array(vector, dtype=numpy.float64)

    m = len(vector)
    x = numpy.zeros(m)

    for k in range(0, m):
        for r in range(k+1, m):
            factor=(matrix[r,k]/matrix[k,k])
            vector[r]=vector[r]-(factor*vector[k])
            for c in range(0,m):
                matrix[r,c]=matrix[r,c]-(factor*matrix[k,c])

    x[m-1]=vector[m-1]/matrix[m-1, m-1]

    for r in range(m-2, -1, -1):
        suma = 0
        for c in range(0,m):
            suma=suma+matrix[r,c]*x[c]
        x[r]=(vector[r]-suma)/matrix[r, r]  
    return x

print(gaussJordan([[2,6,1],[1,2,-1],[5,7,-4]],[7,-1,9]))
```

**Salida:**

> [ 10.  -3.   5.]

Comment: Wow pero que buena explicacion, muchisimas gracias man